# removeAll from Interface Set

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I want to compare database dump to xml and *.sql. In debagge `toRemove` and `toAdd` only differ in dimension. `toRemove` has size 3, `toAdd` has size 4. But after running the code, `removeAll`, `toRemove` has size 3 and `toAdd` has size 4. What's wrong?

```
final DBHashSet fromdb = new DBHashSet(strURL, strUser, strPassword);
final DBHashSet fromxml = new DBHashSet(namefile);

Set<DBRecord> toRemove = new HashSet<DBRecord>(fromdb);
toRemove.removeAll(fromxml);

Set<DBRecord> toAdd = new HashSet<DBRecord>(fromxml);
toAdd.removeAll(fromdb);
```

Update:

```
public class DBRecord {
    public String depcode;
    public String depjob;
    public String description;

    public DBRecord(String newdepcode, String newdepjobe, String newdesc) {
        this.depcode = newdepcode;
        this.depjob = newdepjobe;
        this.description = newdesc;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return depcode + depjob;
    }

    public boolean IsEqualsKey(DBRecord rec) {
        return (this.getKey().equals(rec.getKey()));
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (!(getClass() == o.getClass()))
            return false;
        else {
            DBRecord rec = (DBRecord) o;
            if ((rec.depcode.equals(this.depcode)) && (rec.depjob.equals(this.depjob)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your `hashCode` and `equals()` implementations.

Comment: can we see your DBRecord class?

Comment: Update post with class DBrecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly use `HashSet` (and `HashMap`, for that matter), you must implement a `hashCode()` as per the [following contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

The code you've supplied for `DBRecord` does not overide it, hence the problem.
You'd probably want to override it in the following way, or something similar:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + depcode.hashCode();
  result = prime * result + depjob.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```